# Separar datos de listado numérico interno

Tags: flutter

Estoy creando un listado que lleno con numero 1= si, 2= no,

entonces en un texto quiero que solo muestre la cantidad de 2 que hay sin contar los 1. Todo esto se almacena en el mismo teléfono.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```dart
Text('${_itemDSubsoladotraslape.isEmpty ? 0 : (_itemDSubsoladotraslape.map((e) => e.vlrMuestra).reduce((a, b) => a + b)).toStringAsFixed(2)}'),
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías usar la condición `where` y filtrar por el valor que deseas, luego solo obtienes la cantidad, quedaría así:

```dart
 final cantidadDeDos = _itemDSubsoladotraslape.where((item) => item.vlrMuestra == 2).length;
 print('Dos: $cantidadDeDos');
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me funciono completamente.